# how to install tmux from source

Tags: software-installation, tmux

I've successfully compiled tmux from source and followed instructions. Now I want to installing it, alongside man pages & bash auto completion.

I cannot find the instructions to do so.

EDIT:
instructions were followed from tmux github page: https://github.com/tmux/tmux

that is:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tmux/tmux.git
$ cd tmux
$ sh autogen.sh
$ ./configure && make
```

Comment: So as far as I understand you want to be able to use TAB autocompletion to bring up `tmux`, as well as type it in as `user@host: $ tmux` ,not type full path. Is that correct ?

Comment: Does `sudo make install` work? Advanced tip: use [checkinstall](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/) in order to ease removal of the source installation (the listed will install a potentially unstable version).

Comment: ```sudo make install``` did the trick. Thank you :)

Comment: @lpp make it an answer so people can see it clearly

Comment: Installation instructions are in README.md file from https://github.com/tmux/tmux.